# Get dimensions of an image after render finishes, in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, image, events

I am trying to get the rendered size of an image in a component. Using the (load) event, I am getting the size of the image as it is displayed at that moment (pic1) and the "final" size after the page fully renders. I guess I can use ngAfterViewChecked but that would mean I am constantly calculating that size when the only meaningful instance for that is when the window opens or resizes

[image: (load) event fires]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Mutation Observer, watching for attribute changes, attached to the item that contains the image. In my case there is a need for some management because it doesn't just run once, but it solves the issue

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.refElement = this.appsContainer.nativeElement.querySelector('item') as HTMLElement;
  const config = { attributes: true };
  this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutation) => {
    const target = mutation[0].target as HTMLElement;
    //some code here to execute based on some conditions and to remove the observer 
   }
  });
this.mutationObserver.observe(this.refElement, config);}
```

Answer (score 1):

- An alternate approach that you can use is, subscribe to changes in `Window: resize` event using the `HostListener` in order to calculate image dimensions, as shown in the following code snippet.

```js
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  // Invoke function to compute the image dimensions here
}
```

**Note**: You can also invoke the function to compute the dimensions of the said image inside `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook rather than on `load` event.

- Another approach is to calculate image dimensions by listening to changes in the `Window: resize` event using the `fromEvent`, as shown in the code snippet below.

```js
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

changeSubscription$: Subscription

ngOnInit() {
  this.windowResizeEventChanges$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').subscribe(event => {
    // Invoke function to compute the image dimensions here
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.windowResizeEventChangesn$.unsubscribe() // Unsubscribe to stop listening the changes in Window: resize
}
```

Read more about `fromEvent` [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent).

Comment: Though I guess this is towards the correct path, the issue with this implementation is that the window size doesn't actually change. I am already using this method to calculate the size of the image when the window is resize which does work and this is how I noticed that it doesn't work when the page first loads (on a restored window state)